# Should I use ProptTypes for props I pass through a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Should I use PropTypes for props I pass through a React component to a child component, but don't actually use within component itself?

In the following example, `Component2` would have `PropTypes` for the props received from `Component1`, even though `Component3` is the component using the props.

```
<Component1 someValue=someValue">
  <Component2 {...props}>
    <Component3>
      <div>Hello World! {someValue}</div>
    </Component3>
  </Component2>
</Component1>
```

Comment: IMHO use case for propTypes in react is to typeCheck the props "passed" rather than props "used". So ideally I would place the propTypes where the props are being accepted just for readability.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually write something like this. It makes the code more readable and instantly tells some other developer about your intent

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
 someValue: PropTypes.string,
 ...Component2.propTypes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, its enough to declare propTypes for props that Parent component is using and if rest of props is just passed through, then it's Children component responsibility to validate them. This way you avoid repeating yourself and still get error validation.